# Unable to Start Nifi | Database nay be already in use : "Locked by another process"

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to start nifi but facing h2.jdbc.jdbcSqlException : Database my be already in used exception.

```
2017-02-20 16:09:04,189 INFO [main] /nifi-api No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2017-02-20 16:09:04,218 INFO [main] /nifi-api Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2017-02-20 16:09:05,791 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Determined default nifi.properties path to be '/opt/nifi/current/./conf/nifi.properties'
2017-02-20 16:09:05,793 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Determined default nifi.properties path to be '/opt/nifi/current/./conf/nifi.properties'
2017-02-20 16:09:05,794 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Loaded 115 properties from /opt/nifi/current/./conf/nifi.properties
2017-02-20 16:09:07,878 ERROR [main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'niFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration.setJwtAuthenticationProvider(org.apache.nifi.web.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationProvider); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jwtService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtService' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyService' defined in class path resource [nifi-administration-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyTransactionBuilder' while setting bean property 'transactionBuilder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyTransactionBuilder' defined in class path resource [nifi-administration-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyDataSource': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-176]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:837) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:533) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:810) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404) [jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366) [jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520) [jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:651) [nifi-jetty-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:152) [nifi-runtime-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:243) [nifi-runtime-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiWebApiSecurityConfiguration.setJwtAuthenticationProvider(org.apache.nifi.web.security.jwt.JwtAuthenticationProvider); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jwtService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtService' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyService' defined in class path resource [nifi-administration-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyTransactionBuilder' while setting bean property 'transactionBuilder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyTransactionBuilder' defined in class path resource [nifi-administration-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyDataSource': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-176]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jwtService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtService' defined in class path resource [nifi-web-security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyService' defined in class path resource [nifi-administration-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyTransactionBuilder' while setting bean property 'transactionBuilder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyTransactionBuilder' defined in class path resource [nifi-administration-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'keyDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keyDataSource': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-176]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at ...
```

Looks like nifi is trying to communicate with h2 but unable to do that.

Any pointers for fixing this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check kill if any existing nifi instance is running:-

ps -ef | grep nifi

after that restart your nifi. Let me know if this works for you.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Thanks. Another instance of nifi was running in background.